# How do I know when my wooden floor has fully dried out post-flood?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, water-damage

So I had a bit of a flood (tap overflowing) and the wooden floor in my house was under an inch of water for a few hours. It's drying out now, and is a bit warped but otherwise fine.  I need to wait until it's dry to assess the damage and move the furniture back downstairs, but what I don't know is how to tell when it's dried out.  What moisture content should the floor have?  What should I measure it with?

If I need to provide more details etc. then let me know.  All answers/links to relevant info will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get yourself a moisture meter ($30~) and test the floor at various points.

Wood is rarely COMPLETELY dry (as in no moisture at all) - but you definitely want a moisture content that compares to other wood in your house that was not flooded.

[Example of a moisture meter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00275F5O2)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've found a couple articles that might be very helpful for anyone who see's this in the future. It's always good to know about [acceptable moisture levels in wood](https://www.wagnermeters.com/moisture-meters/wood-info/acceptable-moisture-levels-wood/) before installing floors or working with any kind of wood. [How long does it take to acclimate hardwood flooring?](https://www.wagnermeters.com/moisture-meters/wood-info/how-long-acclimate-wood-flooring/)

I know this is an old post but if anyone wants a great suggestion for a reliable and extremely [accurate moisture meter check out Wanger Meters](https://www.wagnermeters.com/moisture-meters/). I saw a video this summer from a woodworker I follow on Instagram and after watching it I had to upgrade my moisture meter. I used to have a very cheap one but you get what you pay for.